# Error when simulating cURL using a REST call in java

Tags: java, json, rest, curl

Currently I am able to run the following command in curl which returns the json response as expected. Note that the input JSON is sent by name "json" in the request as a form parameter. The API will accept only JSON requests and will only support POST method calls.

Request

```
curl --data 'json={ "startdate": "2012-10-10", "enddate":"2012-10-11" }' http://xxxxx.xxxx.xxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx
```

Response

```
{"startdate":"2012-10-10","status":"true","Api Name":"xxxx","output":{"ROW":"49","EU":"54","NA":"33"},"enddate":"2012-10-11"}
```

I am simulating the above cURL command using a REST call in java.

The code is shown below

```
String urlString = "http://xxxxx.xxxx.xxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx";
URL myUrl = new URL(urlString);
URLConnection urlConn = myUrl.openConnection();

String myData = "json={ \"startdate\": \"2012-10-10\", \"enddate\":\"2012-10-11\" }" ;
urlConn.setRequestProperty("data", myData);

urlConn.connect();

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()));

String inputLine;

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(inputLine);
}
in.close();
```

But the above code returns the following error.

The stack trace is shown below.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 405 for URL: http://xxxxx.xxxx.xxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1615)
    at dashboard.access.data.RAccess.main(RAccess.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe:

```
urlConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
```

after `openConnection()` will fix it? You said your api only allow post requests. And you get a 405 method not allowed.

If not, you can try this link, check out the sendPost() method in first Java `HttpURLConnection example` chapter:
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/

Comment: Since I am using URLConnection, I can't use the setRequestMethod. But the sendPost method in the `example` works great. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

**Please ensure implemented security is correct in the below files.**

> AuthenticationFilter.java
>
> AutherizationFilter.java
>
> SecurityConstants.java
>
> WebSecurity.java

Bcz spring security is the implementation by spring and we are unable to locate the correct exception position.

Comment: I am not sure they need to go that far for now. 
The question doesn't reference any of the classes that you are mentioning.
Better keep it simple. They should start with the conection itself.
The error message mentions HTTP method not allowed. 
So a good start would be looking at what te code they wrote actually does when using URLs and connections? Maybe it does a GET instead of a POST.
Are they maybe approachging this the wrong way?
I would actually assume that reading from a URL connection defaults to a GET verb.